# wp cron task update results every 5 min

Tags: php, json, wordpress, cron

I'm having a result function/shortcode which output data from a json script. This json script is being updated every 5 minutes so I would like to make a cron task for this function to update it self every 5 minutes without duplicating the content on the page.

How can this be done on a wordpress page?

```
function resultpage() {
    $output = '';

    $output .= '<div id="content">';
    $output .= '<div id="part-1">';
    $output .= getgames("lol");
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= ' <div id="part-2">';
    $output .= getgames("counterstrike");
    $output .= ' </div>';
    $output .= ' <div id="part-3">';
    $output .= getgames("dota2");
    $output .= ' </div>';
    $output .= ' <div id="part-4">';
    $output .= getgames("hearthstone");
    $output .= ' </div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('resultpage', 'resultpage');

 add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'cron_add_5min' );

 function cron_add_5min( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['5min'] = array(
        'interval' => 5*60,
        'display' => __( 'Once every five minutes' )
    );
    return $schedules;
 }

add_action( 'init', 'register_result');

function register_result() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'resultpage' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'resultpage' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this instruction [Customizing the WP Schedule event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103262/customizing-the-wp-schedule-event). But you can add a cron tab manually.

1. Create an URL where your function is written.
2. run the command `crontab -e`
3. add a job the example as:

`*/5 * * * * curl http://your_domain.com/file_where_function_is_written.php`

Comment: it is written in a themes function.php? im not sure i can access that through url?